# Same shipping rule name in different methods not allowed?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, shipping

We are setting up shipping methods and rules as follows:

Methods: FedEx Standard, FedEx Priority, FedEx Overnight

For each method we wanted to add the following rules: US, Canada, International

However, when trying to add another rule for another Shipping Method, we get this error:

`CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'Canada' for key 'craft_commerce_shippingrules_name_unq_idx'`

I assume we cannot have duplicate rule names across different methods? If so, this seems odd. Of course we can make each rule have a unique name (ex. US Standard, US Prioriy, etc) but it seems like unnecessary complication. Is that our only option?

Comment: I feel like I saw this go past on slack as a bug a while ago....& I thought​ Luke fixed it.... Are you running the latest Commerce?

Comment: Interesting... yes, we are running the latest version and I wondered if it was possibly a bug. Maybe I'll send this in to support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirmed by Luke this was due to a bug to be fixed in the next release of Commerce.